# Filtering without pattern matching

Tags: sml

I have a function that takes `(string * (int * int * int)) list * string` as an argument and gives `(string * (int * int * int)) list` as a result.
So I have a list with `(string * (int * int * int))` values, and i need to filter it by `string` without using pattern matching. Once the filtering is done, the function gives filtered list with `(string * (int * int * int))` values.
For example it should work like this:

```
- listCars ( [ ("Samsung", (1,2,3)), ("Hyundai", (3,4,5)), ("Mersedes", (6,1,5))], "Vehicle" );
> val it = [("Hyundai", (3,4,5)), ("Mersedes", (6,1,5))] : (string * (int * int * int)) list
```

The function itself:

```
fun listCars ( (lst, type) 
                  : (string * (int * int * int)) list * string) 
                  : (string * (int * int * int)) list = 
let
  fun f (rez : (string * (int * int * int)) list
            , l : (string * (int * int * int)) list)
            : (string * (int * int * int)) list =
    if whatType (hd (l)) = type then rez @ [hd (l)]
    else f (rez, tl (l))
in f ([], lst)
end
```

But when I perform the above example on this function

```
listCars ( [ ("Samsung", (1,2,3)), ("Hyundai", (3,4,5)), ("Mersedes", (6,1,5))], "Vehicle" );
```

it only gives me

```
> val it = [("Hyundai", (3,4,5))] : (string * (int * int * int)) list
```

Expected output:

```
> val it = [("Hyundai", (3,4,5)), ("Mersedes", (6,1,5))] : (string * (int * int * int)) list
```

So basically it's not adding all of the corresponding elements to the new list, I assume I'm doing something wrong in this line: `if whatType (hd (l)) = type then rez @ [hd (l)]` when I'm trying to add corresponding elements to a new list. What's my mistake?

Comment: How is "whatType" doing it's stuff ? As a guess, I think, you should be calling f over (rez @ (hd (l))) tl(l)...
if whatType (hd (l)) = type then f (rez @ [hd (l)]) tl(l)...
or something like that.. unless you give what "whatType" does, I can only make a guess... also please elaborate your expected output.

Comment: I'm guessing from context that `whatType` determines what type of product a provided manufacturer uses.

Comment: Why is pattern-matching not permitted? This would be much cleaner and easier to reason out with pattern matching.

Comment: @NalinRanjan it depends on a bunch of other functions, so i assume it would be unnecesary to write them all. Basically it takes `(name, (num1, num2, num2)) : string * (int * int * int)` and based on numbers returns a 'type' of argument as a `string`. Example of usage: `whatType ("Hyundai", (3,4,5)) = "Vehicle"` So since numbers are `(3,4,5)` the function told us that our value is a `"Vehicle"`. Hope my explanation is good enough

Comment: @ChrisDutton yes, your explanation about `whatType` is correct. I can't use pattern-matching because my assignment restricts me from it

Comment: ok.. makes sense if it's too entwined.. Then you should try recursing over the rest of the list in that if condition.... Because if first element itself is picked by the if clause, then we are simply appending and done.. which is causing rest of the list unprocessed..Try following under the if clause...if whatType (hd (l)) = type then f (rez @ [hd (l)]) tl(l) else ....

Comment: But then you also will have to handle the empty list condition...

Comment: "it depends on a bunch of other functions, so i assume it would be unnecesary to write them all" why assume that? Posting a [mcve] is always preferable to posting a code fragment that others can't run without undue effort on their part.

Answer (score 2):

When you're dealing with recursion, it's critical to establish a base case. The result of filtering an empty list should obviously be an empty list.

```
fun listCars (lst, productType) =
  if lst = [] then
    []
```

Next, what's our case when the first element in the list does match the desired product type? Well, it's that first element, added to the front of the result of filtering the rest of the list.

```
fun listCars (lst, productType) =
  if lst = [] then
    []
  else if whatType (hd lst) = productType then
    hd lst :: listCars (tl lst, productType)
```

And finally we need to handle that first element not satisfying the condition, by just running the filter on the remaining elements.

```
fun listCars (lst, productType) =
  if lst = [] then
    []
  else if whatType (hd lst) = productType then
    hd lst :: listCars (tl lst, productType)
  else
    listCars (tl lst, productType)
```

You'll please note that all of the type annotations are *not* required. Your SML compiler or interpreter environment will infer the types as needed. You can use the type annotations to limit the types, though.

Now it looks like you were writing this for tail recursion as you were using a helper function. The conditions we need to handle are the same. We just need an accumulator that starts off as `[]`.

```
fun listCars (lst, productType) =
  let 
    fun aux (result, lst, productType) =
      if lst = [] then
        result
      else if whatType (hd lst) = productType then
        listCars (result @ [hd lst], tl lst, productType)
      else
        listCars (result, tl lst, productType) 
  in
    aux ([], lst, productType)
  end
```

Please note, here is what this function looks like *with* pattern matching.

```
fun listCars ([], _) = []
  | listCars (lst, productType) =
  let 
    fun aux (result, [], _) = result
      | aux (result, hd::tl, productType) =
      if whatType hd = productType then
        listCars (result @ [hd], tl, productType)
      else
        listCars (result, tl, productType) 
  in
    aux ([], lst, productType)
  end
```

Pattern matching or not, the key to recursion is to think through it systematically.

Comment: @mutter123, this reply has tonnes of information for you .. specifically if you are learning... Hopefully, you should get what you need if you can follow this reply...